# How to change the text in a list of tables/ list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have chosen to describe the tables/figures I have in the table caption. As a result the list of tables/list of figures gives the whole table description as the caption. Is it a way change this so the list of tables/figures only contain the name of the table/figure that I set?

[image]

Comment: `\caption[<text for the list of tables>]{<long version of the caption including the description>}` should result in the expected output

Comment: Please supply an MWE (`\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what yo have done and your problem that we can compile in order to help you. Where in the LoF does "panel"? come from? Should it bump over into the following text, wherever that came from?